# Bind Ctrl+Down in Joe on a Linux console

Tags: linux, terminal, console, key-mapping, joe

When I want to select a line in `joe` editor, I can go to the beginning and simply pres <kbd>CTRL-Down</kbd> and this will select the line. I can move somewhere ales and copy the line with <kbd>CTRL-k-c</kbd>.

The key code corresonding to <kbd>CTRL-Down</kbd> is `^[[1;5B` and I see this is defined in joe's config file `/etc/joe/joerc`:

```
dnarw,uparw,begin_marking,dnarw,toggle_marking  ^[ [ 1 ; 5 B    Mark down
```

The above described works when I am in a virtual terminal, i.e. `terminator`. When I am in a console (i.e. <kbd>CTRL-ALT-F2</kbd>, it does not work anymore. Moreover, I have noticed that when I pres <kbd>CTRL-Down</kbd> in console, I get another code: `^[[B`.

I am using console a lot and I would like to have the possibility to use the "Mark Down" feature. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

There's one big issue here: under the linux console there's no way to distinguish <kbd>Ctrl-Down</kbd> from <kbd>Down</kbd>, they both send the same `^[[B` sequence.

To make it work we'd need to find a hack for the linux console to change that. Not pretty, but if you care enough about it it might be possible.

Otherwise, how about using another key binding ? Say <kbd>Alt-/</kbd>,
Just need to add this to `/etc/joe/joerc` next to the other one:

```
dnarw,uparw,begin_marking,dnarw,toggle_marking  ^[ /            Mark down
```

and now it works in the terminal and console =)

Comment: you are right, they both send `^[[B`. Why is that ? Is there no way to make `Ctrl-Down` different from `Down` ? I cannot use another key binding, that would just confuse me.